# lwp-request Fails After Upgrade to Centos 7

Tags: centos, perl, ssl

I have a bash script that runs well on centos 6, which has an lwp-request in it.
I upgraded my system to Centos 7, and the request fails to run:

```
# lwp-request -E https://localhost/admin/startup
GET https://localhost/admin/startup
User-Agent: lwp-request/6.03 libwww-perl/6.05

500 Can't connect to localhost:443
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Sun, 25 Jan 2015 10:24:22 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

Can't connect to localhost:443
```

I verified that the url is reachable via browser.
My assumption is that this is a perl-libraries-update issue.
What perl libs are required for SSL/TLS networking with lwp-request?
Or what was changed in these libs:

```
perl-libwww-perl
perl-Crypt-SSLeay
```

**NOTICE**
In Centos 7 I got these (and some more) new libs installed that might be related to this:

```
perl-Net-SSLeay
perl-IO-Socket-SSL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO::Socket::SSL verifies that the name in the certificate matches the name you connect to, but Crypt::SSLeay does not. Newer LWP also verify the certificate chain by default, but maybe this was also done with the older LWP version you used.

I recommend you call your program with SSL debugging to see the actual cause of the problem:

```
perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 program.pl
```

Then you can control with `ssl_opts` which checks should be done, see `perldoc IO::Socket::SSL` for more details about the options:

- Use `SSL_ca_file` if you are using a self-signed certificate or if the certificate is not issued by any of the commonly trusted root CAs.
- Use `SSL_verifycn_name` to set the name it should expect in the certificate. That is if you have a name for `www.example.com` in the certificate but connect to the host with `localhost` you should set `SSL_verifycn_name => 'www.example.com'`
- Alternatively you could use `SSL_fingerprint` to check only the fingerprint of the certificate and disable any other checks.
- And finally you could disable any kind of verification with `SSL_verify_mode`. But this is only a workaround and you should never do this in production code, because this makes you open for man-in-the-middle attacks.

Since you can not set ssl_opts directly with `lwp-request` I recommend to use instead a small program instead, i.e. something like this:

```
  use LWP::UserAgent;
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { 
      SSL_ca_file => 'myca.pem',
      SSL_verifycn_name => 'www.example.com',
  });
  print $ua->get('https://...')->as_string;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I trace the lwp-request, to know what perl modules are being used? How can I be sure the new libs are used at all?

Comment: You might check with `strace -e open lwp-request ...` if the file `some_path/IO/Socket/SSL.pm` gets read by the program.

Comment: "I verified that the url is reachable via browser." - do you get any error messages inside the browser? I think it should at least complain about name in the certificate not matching the hostname you used, because certificates for `localhost` usually don't get issued.

Comment: `strace` does show io-socket-ssl is used. I'm new to perl... can you show how to edit the ssl_opts to set SSL_ca_file to undefined?

Comment: @csny: see edited answer. For CA file/path you could also use the environment variables PERL_LWP_SSL_CA_FILE and PERL_LWP_SSL_CA_PATH.

Comment: Thanks! I nested the perl code inside the bash script instead of the lwp-request, and it works just as good :)